# Switch function runs but the cases are just ignored

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a program that loops through a list box checking to see what is selected.  I have a switch function that runs once an item in the list box is selected and a check box is checked.

```
for (var i = 0;i <= returnDate.length; i++) {
        if (checkOutBoxs[i].checked == 1) {
            var time=0;
            switch (returnDate){
                case 0:
                    time=24*60*60*1000;//1 Day
                    break;
                case 1:
                    time=3*24*60*60*1000;//.5 Week
                    break;
                case 2:
                    time=7*24*60*60*1000;//1 Week
                    break;
                case 3:
                    time=14*24*60*60*1000;//2 Weeks
                    break;
                case 4:
                    time=21*24*60*60*1000;//3 Weeks
                    break;
                case 5:
                    time=28*24*60*60*1000;//1 Month
                    break;
                default:
                    time="0";  
            }
```

The returnDate is an array of all my list boxs and the checkOutBoxs is a checkbox.

Comment: try `switch (returnDate[i]){`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`returnDate` is an array and you are comparing it to a number.  That should always be false except when `returnDate = []`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean:

```
switch(i)
```

or

```
switch(returnDate[i])
```

You cannot compare to int when you switch an array.

Comment: You can switch on an array.  The comparison will just yield false practically all the time.

Answer (score 0):

The only case, which should work is 0 -> returndate=[]==0. But that would not be, what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

Switch-case statements do not play nicely with arrays in Javascript. Try changing your `switch` line to `switch (returnDate[i]) {`. If your array stores integers, this should get you closer to what you want.